# Need to re arrange all records into same rows

Tags: mysql

I need the following code to have all three `proj1`, `proj4` and `proj5` columns to be together in one row each according to dates.

As you can see dates are similar but it is showing in different records.

[image]

MYSQL Query is as follows:

```
select DISTINCT dates,proj1,proj4, proj5 from 
    (SELECT DISTINCT tc.dates AS dates , IF( tc.project_id = 1, tc.minutes, '' ) AS 'proj1',
    IF(tc.project_id = 5, tc.minutes, '') AS 'proj5', IF(tc.project_id = 4, tc.minutes, '') AS 'proj4'
FROM timecard AS tc where (tc.dates between '2013-04-01' AND '2013-04-05') ) as X
```

I need all three `proj1` , `proj4` and `proj5` records to display all in same rows and then query should have only 5 rows

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 1):

You can group by the `dates` and then use `max()` to show values that are not empty

```
select dates, max(proj1) as proj1, max(proj4) as proj4, max(proj5) as proj5
from timecard 
where tc.dates between '2013-04-01' AND '2013-04-05'
group by dates
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this sql.

```
select dates,
        (case t1.proj1
        when t1.proj1 not null then t1.proj1 
        when t2.proj1 not null then t2.proj1
        when t3.proj1 not null then t3.proj1
        end) as "proj1",
        (case t1.proj2
        when t1.proj2 not null then t1.proj2 
        when t2.proj2 not null then t2.proj2
        when t3.proj2 not null then t3.proj2
        end) as "proj2",
        (case t1.proj3
        when t1.proj3 not null then t1.proj3 
        when t2.proj3 not null then t2.proj3
        when t3.proj3 not null then t3.proj3
        end) as "proj3"
from timecard t1,timecardt2,timecardt3
where t1.dates=t2.dates
and t2.dates=t3.dates
group by t1.dates
```